# Why are there 31 solutions to this problem?

Tags: trigonometry

How many positive numbers $x$ satisfy the equation $\cos{97x} = x$?
What procedure should I use to find the number of possible solutions?

Comment: Are you measuring angles in degrees or radians? Have you drawn a diagram?

Comment: What is the period of $\cos(97x)$? How many $\cos$ waves are there across $[0,1]$?

Comment: @MarkBennet I'm not given any othe information. I'm not sure whether to use radians or degrees. I'm not sure how to plot cos(97x) - x.

Comment: Where's this problem from? I feel like I saw it just a while ago

Comment: @DavidMitra 2Pi/97?

Comment: @Nitin It's from the GRE Math Subject Test.

Comment: Hint: The general idea is that $\cos$ function spans the $[-1,1]$ region. You have to find out how many cycles does  $\cos{97x}$ do when $x\in[0,1]$, while taking care of the extrema, such as you don't add or remove a viable solution.

Comment: So, there are approximately 15.4 ($97/(2\pi)$) $\cos$ waves across $[0,1]$. The number of solutions is the number of times the graph of $y=\cos 97x$ intersects the line $y=x$ over $[0,1]$. Sketching the graphs of $y=\cos 97x$ and $y=x$ gives this number as $31$.

Comment: @DavidMitra  What do you mean by 15.4 cos waves? The y= cos97x intersects y=x 31 times?

Comment: A "$\cos$ wave" is one full period (so there is one wave of $\cos x$ over $[0,2\pi]$, two waves of $\cos 4x$ over $[0,\pi]$, etc...). Each full  wave, here, gives two solutions.

Comment: Here is the [online plot](http://www.fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4LWNvcyg5Nyp4KSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMCwid2luZG93IjpbIi0wLjAxNjg5NjM4NzMyNDA1NzA4NiIsIjEuMjkyODc0Njc1MzUzNDk5NCIsIi0xLjY3NzE0NTM4NTc0MjE4NiIsIjMuMDkxMjI2MTk2Mjg5MDYwNCJdLCJzaXplIjpbMTEwMCw4MDBdfV0-) confirming the answer 31.

Comment: If you draw the graphs of $y=\cos 97x$ and $y=x$ you will see where they intersect. Or you can put $z=97x$ and draw $y=\cos z$ against $y=\frac z{97}$. In this reformulated problem, you can draw the graph of $y=\cos z$ and explore what happens if you substitute $2$ or $5$ or some other $n$ for $97$ - if you have a ruler and a piece of paper, you will find that as $n$ increases, the ruler comes closer to the axis, and you should get some idea what is happening. Worth doing because next time you see something like this it might not be $\cos$ and it certainly won't be $97$ - so get the idea.